# How to read sharePoint List item value (current Item) using javascript

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint

I have to read **Title and Location** from a picture library and display using CEWP.

Can someone suggest how to read SharePoint list item values using Javascript.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the JavaScript Client Object Model. Assuming the window's `_spPageContextInfo` object is set with the `webServerRelativeUrl`, `pageListId`, and `pageItemId` properties initialized:

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
var item = list.getItemById(_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId);
```

Then you can load the fields you need:

```
context.load(item, "Title", "Location");
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.mySuccessFunction), Function.createDelegate(this, this.myErrorFunction));
```

`item` will now be populated with the fields you requested, and you can retrieve them like so:

```
var itemTitle = item.get_item("Title");
var itemLocation = item.get_item("Location");
```

Note that you should use the display, not internal, names of the fields you want to load.

Comment: I'm trying to read the pageItemId from the _spPageContextInfo global but it doesn't have that property. I'm in a display form. Help? :\

Comment: Nevermind... I just checked it out, that property only exists when the list is a document library. Good answer anyway.

Comment: Yes it does, if you instantiate web object to own variable.
 var web = ctx.get_web();

Answer (score 3):

In SharePoint 2010 there are three different types of Client Object Model extension you can use. They are Managed Client Object Model, ECMAScript and silverlight extension.

This link more close to your requirement [How to: Retrieve Lists Using JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185009.aspx)
and  [How do you get the current list item in JavaScript?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11169/how-do-you-get-the-current-list-item-in-javascript)

[**SP.ListOperation.Selection Methods**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407815.aspx)

```
var value = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
```

Check following links for more information:
[SharePoint 2010: Use ECMAScript to manipulate (Add/Delete/Update/Get) List Items](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2010/07/sharepoint-2010-use-ecmascript-to.html)
[Accessing List Data using the JavaScript Client OM](http://sharepointbloggin.com/2010/02/10/walkthrough-4-accessing-list-data-using-the-javascript-client-om/)
[Using the SP2010 Client Object Model to update a list item](http://blog.dennus.net/2010/07/20/using-the-sp2010-client-object-model-to-update-a-list-item/)
[How to – SharePoint 2010 – JS client object model and UI advancements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/02/25/how-to-sharepoint-2010-js-client-object-model-and-ui-advancements.aspx)

Comment: I am getting error "TypeError: SP.ListOperation is undefined". Can you suggest anything to fix this issue?

Comment: I tried to put in both `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ReadCustomvalue, "sp.js")` &
       `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', ReadCustomvalue)`. But both of them didn't fix this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to access the list items via SharePoint Web Services. Refer for example here - [SharePoint Web Services with jQuery](http://mydevexperience.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/sharepoint-list-access-part-i-how-to-access-sharepoint-list-web-service-using-jquery-entirely-client-side-only/)

Answer (score 1):

```
if _spPageContextInfo.pageItemId is undefined.
Use this function
function getUrlVars() {
var vars = [],
    hash;
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}
return vars;
}
//THEN DO THIS
var id = getUrlVars()["ID"];
//THEN DO YOUR MAGIC
var context = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
var item = list.getItemById(id);
```

Answer (score -1):

In SP2010 there is new client APIs that allow you to interact with SharePoint sites from JavaScript

[SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537247.aspx)

[JavaScript Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538253.aspx)